# Why does charge distribute itself uniformly only on the surface of spherical conductors?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, conductors

I understand why charge does not distribute itself uniformly on the surface of a conductor of any other shape. I do not understand why charge distributes itself uniformly only on the surface of a spherical conductor.

Comment: It also distributes itself evenly on an infinite cylinder or infinite plane. In fact, it will distribute itself evenly over any surface with uniform curvature.

Comment: Oh ok, I am basing this off of Walter Lewin's 8.02 lectures.

Comment: Call of symmetry.

Comment: It will work only for the hollow spherical shells ...right? You can further read about **Faraday's Electrostatic Shielding**

Answer (score 2):

The charge distributes uniformly on the surface of a spherical conductor (which is far from any other body) due to the spherical symmetry of the problem. There is no reason why it should accumulate at any location of the surface more than at any other location. Therefore it is distributed uniformly. Also, if it was distributed inhomogeneously, the electric fields would produce currents that redistribute the charge until there is no electric field inside and tangential to the surface.

Answer (score 0):

By definition of a conductor (in equilibrium with no potential applied), the whole body must be at the same potential. That it must have no fields inside it otherwise the molecules will orient itself until their is no field inside it.
So Consider a solid spherical conductor. Take the spherical symmetrical Gaussian surface of radius less than the radius of the conductor.
Observe that the inside field must be zero by the above argument. So the net flux going through the Gaussian surface must also be zero. So there is no net charge inside the sphere.
This can be done for all Gaussian surfaces until we get to the surface, where we are no longer inside the conductor and Electric field can now exist.
Hence when you put charge on the conductor it goes to the outside.
PS- This type of reasoning can be put forward with a conductor of any shape.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.  The OP agrees that the charge should be on the surface;  the question is why this distribution is uniform on the surface of a sphere.

Comment: I do not understand **why charge distributes itself uniformly only on the surface**. I think it could be reasoned the way I did.

Comment: The definition of a conductor **does not** include that it must be on the same potential! Think, e.g.,  of a wire with an applied potential difference.

Comment: Nice catch, but the conductor I'm taking about does not have any applied potential. I'll edit it to make it more clear.

Comment: It's the "uniformly" part that I'm concerned with.  Unless I've missed something in your argument, all you've shown is that the charge is on the surface, not that it must be uniformly distributed.

Comment: Based on Walter Lewin's lecture, I think he means that surfaces with uniform surface area tend to have the same amount of charge over that region, therefore they have the same surface charge density. And if we analyze surfaces with the same area, they will have the same amount of charge.

Answer (score 0):

The below addresses the word "uniformly distributed over the surface"
Solving the Laplacian equation may help.
The spherical conductor is equipotential at the surface, say $V_{0}$
Set the potential at infinity as zero
Then, we can solve the Laplacian Equation in the vacuum $\nabla^2{V}=0$ with the boundary condition specified.
Using spherical coordinate separation of variables,
the solution is $V = \frac{V_0R}{r}$  (or just verify this solution and then by the uniqueness theorem, it holds.)
Then, by the boundary condition of $\vec E$, at the surface,
$\partial_r V_{above}-\partial_r V_{below}$ 
= $-\frac{-V_0 R}{R^2}- 0$ (substitute r = R)
= $-\frac{-V_0 }{R}$
$= -\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_0}$
so $\sigma = \frac{\epsilon_0 V_0}{R}$
$\sigma$ being a constant is the same as saying the surface charge density is constant over the conductor, which is the same as saying the spherical conductor surface is uniformly charged.

To address the word "only on the surface", here is a quick argument
Since the E field is zero in the conductor, by Gauss's law, the charge density inside is also zero. Therefore, all the charges (if have) on a conductor must lie on the surface.

The question "why charge distributes itself uniformly only on the surface of a spherical conductor" should be answered.

Comment: To get as far away from all the other charges.